# errors on Quick sort in Haskell

Tags: haskell, quicksort

Please check my Haskell program code
GHC says it's parse error on input '\' in line 9.
I really don't know how to correct it.

```
    import System.IO
    import Data.Time.Clock
    import Random 
    qsort [] = [] 
    qsort (x:xs) = qsort1 elts_lt_x ++ [x] ++ qsort1 elts_greq_x 
                    where 
                      elts_lt_x   = [y | y <- xs, y < x] 
                      elts_greq_x = [y | y <- xs, y >= x]
    module Main where
    main = do    
        x <- getLine
        gen=mkStdGen 60
        arrays=take (read x) (randomRs (1,(read x)) gen ::[Int])
        start <- getCurrentTime
        print(take 1(qsort arrays))    
        end <- getCurrentTime
        print $ diffUTCTime  end start
```

Answer (score 4):

- The `module ...` line comes before `import ...` .
- I assume that `qsort1` should be `qsort` .
- For value-assignment you need `let`. Such as `let gen = ...` .
- You should consider to use `System.Random` instead of the haskell98 `Random` module.
- There is an discussion about the definition of Quicksort. On [Haskellwiki: Why Haskell Matters](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Why_Haskell_Matters#Elegance) its also called Filtersort.